# Facebook Friend List In Canvas App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am Creating a Facebook App using PHP Language Which i have to read user friend list, I tried a lot but failed,

For example In App Who is your best friend at Facebook(We pick a User profile Pic and one of user friend pic , combine and make a new picture with some styles)My App is similar to this logic, that's why i am asking about it

is it possible that i can read friend list of user using Facebook API?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Graph API, you can get the list of friends that *also* use your app. You **can not** get the full friends list.

You can read more on the user friends edge here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends?locale=en_GB

Here you can read about the basics of the Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2?locale=en_GB